# How to set recording audio few seconds on Android?

Tags: android, audio, wear-os, audio-recording, voice-recording

I am trying to record some audio from microphone on android wear, 3 seconds long. 
In this case we can't do that with `Thread.sleep(3000);` because during those seconds main thread works. 
Also I was trying with manipulate with time and I got current time in seconds from Calendar example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
seconds = seconds + 2;
if (seconds == 60 || seconds == 61)
{
    seconds = seconds - 60;
}
int sada; //with initialization here is pretty much same
do
{
    sada = 105; //without this line is pretty much same
    sada = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    Log.d("SEKUNDI", String.valueOf(sada));
}while(sada != seconds);
```

Anyone help?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by recording audio from "speaker", did you mean microphone?

Comment: Checkout this sample; it records from microphone on a wear device for 10 seconds: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearSpeakerSample

Comment: Create a new Thread, call Thread.sleep(3000) then call runOnUiThread() where you stop the recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started recording in main thread, and I created new thread in background and sleep it for 3 seconds. In a postBack method I called the stopRecording() method. Important code is:

```
Thread.currentThread();
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

This can be applied to any other similar problem. Thanks for comments.